# How to connect to iPhoneSimulator with VS2017 in MAC

Tags: ios, debugging, xamarin.ios, ios-simulator, visual-studio-2017

I am trying to debug my iOS application with iPhone simulator, unfortunately I can't connect to it. It's showing me "Building", but without any success to launch it on simulator.[image]

Comment: I am also get this message in log window: "No such file or directory: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator.sdk/usr/libexec/coreduetd"

Comment: Did you ever figure this one out?

Comment: I've updated all my Packages. Make sure in options->IOS Bundle Signing you put suitable ad-hoc Provision Profile or suitable Debug Provision Profile with Signing Identity.